# OpenLayers not automatically refreshing icons on map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm currently having issues with the web-app I'm developing with OpenLayers.  It currently assigns icons from an API to the OpenLayers map [example with output located here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZBxu.png), and displays information assigned to said icons on a sidebar.  I'm trying to get these icons to refresh automatically on the map without actually refreshing the page, but am running into some issues.  I have confirmed through the console that everything is getting updated, however, new icons are not being created during this.  If anyone here can potentially help, it would be greatly appreciated. I've attached the important parts of the index.js below.  The third code snippet is from the API.

Map index.js:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')
import "ol/ol.css";
import Feature from "ol/Feature";
import Point from "ol/geom/Point";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import Overlay from 'ol/Overlay';
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer } from "ol/layer";
import { defaults as defaultControls, FullScreen } from "ol/control";
import OSM from "ol/source/OSM";
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import StaticVector from "ol/source/Vector";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import { Icon, Style } from "ol/style";
import { type } from "os";
import { Stats } from "fs";

const newportLonLat = [-71.307607, 41.529193];
const mvpLonLat = [-100.622655, 38.051559];
const newportWebMercator = fromLonLat(mvpLonLat);

//const text = 'SELECT DISTINCT mmsi, MAX(basedatetime), lat, lon FROM public.vessels GROUP BY mmsi, lat, lon ORDER by MAX(basedatetime) DESC, mmsi, lat, lon'
var updateMap = setInterval(loadJSON, 3000)
function loadJSON() {
  var data_file = "http://localhost:3000/all";
  var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  try{
     // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari
     http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }catch (e) {
     // Internet Explorer Browsers
     try{
        http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

     }catch (e) {

        try{
           http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
           // Something went wrong
           alert("Your browser broke!");
           return false;
        }

     }
  }

  http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {

     if (http_request.readyState == 4  ) {
        // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
        console.log(http_request);
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
        var allIcons = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < jsonObj.length - 1; i++){ 
          console.log("-----------")
          console.log("Latitude:  ", jsonObj[i]['lat'])
          console.log("Longitude: ", jsonObj[i]['lon'])
          console.log("ID: ", jsonObj[i]['mmsi'])

          var mmsi = jsonObj[i]['mmsi']
          var bdt = jsonObj[i]['basedatetime']
          var lat = jsonObj[i]['lat']
          var long = jsonObj[i]['lon']
          var sog = jsonObj[i]['sog']
          var cog = jsonObj[i]['cog']
          var heading = jsonObj[i]['heading']
          var name = jsonObj[i]['vesselname']
          var imo = jsonObj[i]['imo']
          var callSign = jsonObj[i]['callsign']
          var type = jsonObj[i]['vesseltype']
          var status = jsonObj[i]['status']
          var length = jsonObj[i]['length']
          var width = jsonObj[i]['width']
          var draft = jsonObj[i]['draft']
          var cargo = jsonObj[i]['cargo']

          if(mmsi == -999999) mmsi = "N/A"
          if(bdt == "") bdt = "N/A"
          if(lat == -999999) lat = "N/A"
          if(long == -999999) long = "N/A"
          if(sog == -999999) sog = "N/A"
          if(cog == -999999) cog = "N/A"
          if(heading == -999999) heading = "N/A"
          if(name == "") name = "N/A"
          if(imo == "") imo = "N/A"
          if(callSign == "") callSign = "N/A"
          if(type == -999999) type = "N/A"
          if(status == "") status = "N/A"
          if(length == -999999) length = "N/A"
          if(width == -999999) width = "N/A"
          if(draft == -999999) draft = "N/A"
          if(cargo == -999999) cargo = "N/A"

          var iconFeature = new Feature({
            geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([long, lat])),
            vMmsi: mmsi,
            vName: name,
            vType: type,
            vBDT: bdt,
            vLat: lat,
            vLong: long,
            vStatus: status,
            vSog: sog,
            vCog: cog,
            vHeading: heading,
            vImo: imo,
            vCallSign: callSign,
            vLength: length,
            vWidth: width,
            vDraft: draft,
            vCargo: cargo,
          });

          var iconStyle = new Style({
            image: new Icon(
              /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                src: "https://i.imgur.com/P30vpnp.png",
                scale: 0.5

              })
            )
          });
          iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
          allIcons.push(iconFeature);

        }

        var map = new Map({
          controls: defaultControls().extend([new FullScreen()]),

          layers: [
            new TileLayer({
              source: new OSM()
            }),
            new VectorLayer({
              style: function(feature) {
                return feature.get("style");
              },
              source: new VectorSource({ features: allIcons })

            })

          ],
          target: document.getElementById('map'),
          view: new View({
            center: newportWebMercator,
            zoom: 4
          })
        });
        var element = document.getElementById('popup');

var popup = new Overlay({
  element: element,
  positioning: 'bottom-center',
  stopEvent: false,
  offset: [0, -50]
});

map.addOverlay(popup);

// display popup on click
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature) {
      return feature;
    });
  if (feature) {
    console.log(feature.get('name'))
    document.getElementById("mmsi").innerHTML = feature.get('vMmsi');
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = feature.get('vName');
    document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = feature.get('vType');
    document.getElementById("bdt").innerHTML = feature.get('vBDT');
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = feature.get('vLat');
    document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = feature.get('vLong');
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = feature.get('vStatus');
    document.getElementById("sog").innerHTML = feature.get('vSog');
    document.getElementById("cog").innerHTML = feature.get('vCog');
    document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = feature.get('vHeading');
    document.getElementById("imo").innerHTML = feature.get('vImo');
    document.getElementById("callSign").innerHTML = feature.get('vCallSign');
    document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = feature.get('vLength');
    document.getElementById("width").innerHTML = feature.get('vWidth');
    document.getElementById("draft").innerHTML = feature.get('vDraft');
    document.getElementById("cargo").innerHTML = feature.get('vCargo');
    var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
    popup.setPosition(coordinates);
    $(element).popover({
      placement: 'top',
      html: true,
      content: feature.get('name')
    });
    $(element).popover('show');
  } else {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
  }
});

// change mouse cursor when over marker
map.on('pointermove', function(e) {
  if (e.dragging) {
    $(element).popover('destroy');
    return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(e.originalEvent);
  var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel(pixel);
  map.getTarget().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
});

     }
  }

  http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
  http_request.send();
}
loadJSON();
```

API index.js:

```
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
  })
var timer = setInterval(updateAPI, 15000);
function updateAPI(){
  app.get ('/all', db.allDisplay);
  console.log("API Updated")
}
```

Thank you for your time and all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you include the entire `Map index.js` file.

Comment: @Vivek Just edited the post to include that now, sorry for the late response.

Comment: You will probably need to call `map.render();` after the data is being updated.